# Can I use scipy to check the jacobian of a function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, derivative

I have a function for which I know the explicit expression of the jacobian. I would like to check the correctness of this jacobian by comparing it against a finite-element approximation. Scipy has a [function that does a similar check on the gradient of a function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.check_grad.html) but I haven't found the equivalent for a jacobian (if it existed in scipy, I assume it would be in [this listing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#utilities)). I would like a function that similarly takes two callables (the function and the jacobian) and an ndarray (the points to check the jacobian against its approximation) and returns the error between the two.

The jacobian of a function can be written in a form that uses the gradients of the components of the function, so the `scipy.optimize.check_grad` function might be usable to this extent, but I don't know how that might be implemented in practice.

Say I have function

```py
def fun(x, y):
    return y, x
```

with the jacobian

```py
from numpy import ndarray, zeros
def jac(x, y):
    result = zeros((2, 2))
    result[0, 1] = 1
    result[1, 2] = 1
    return result
```

How should I go about to separate these variables in order to use the scipy function? The solution must be generalizable to n-dimensional functions. Or is there an existing function to fill this task?

If I were limited to 2-dimensional functions, I might do

```py
from scipy.optimize import check_grad

def fun1(x, y):
    return fun(x, y)[0]

def grad1(x, y):
    return jac(x, y0)[0]

check_grad(fun1, grad1, [1.5, -1.5])

...
```

but this solution isn't trivially extended to functions of higher dimensions.

Comment: can see [some examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97235/scipy.optimize.check_grad)

Comment: for `check_grad` -  "The user-provided objective function must return a **scalar** value." - your functions are not returning scalar. Even if you need higher than 2D - you'll have *r=f(x,y,z)*, if not multivariate output... - for such a case see `minimize` of `rosen` func as example used in `scipy`  docs for multidim input -- & NB *continuity* of output & *methods* used for `minimize`... Anyway, `checkgrad` will need *scalar* return that is opposite to your intentions

Comment: can re-write your minimization problem to `tensorflow` lib & monitor [tf.GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#intermediate_results) for intermediate grad results

Answer (score 2):

SciPy is not the best tool for this. You should be using a numerical library that does autograd.

[JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) has a close implementation of the NumPy API and adds [autograd functionality](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/autodiff_cookbook.html).

Other deep learning frameworks such as PyTorch and Tensorflow are able to do the same, but without the simplicity of the NumPy interface.